# Resize flex items to fit parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a two-column layout with flex parent `height: 100vh`. The first column is a div with some heading and a paragraph and the second column has a div with an image. I want flex parent height to be 100vh on all viewports and the image to shrink to fit in the container.
However, the image overflows the container and doesn't shrink. This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image: Desktop]
[image: Mobile]

Here's my code:

```css
.section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%
}

img {
  width: 100%
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Some heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1280px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"></img>
      <div>
    </div>
<section>
```

Comment: Please post your relevant html and css, even if that css isn’t yet working as you wish. Take a look at the “*[ask]*” and “*[mcve]*” guidance for information on why we need, and expect, to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to need to add style to organize layouts

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="fdb-block">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row text-left align-items-center pt-5 pb-md-5">
      <div class="col-md-5 m-md-auto order-md-5">
        <img alt="image" class="img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uUBx.png">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <h2><strong>Feature Two</strong></h2>
        <p class="lead">Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.froala.com">Learn More <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

### Heading

Comment: This code doesn't show images on mobile. Also, the formatting is not correct. 3rd last line should be </div> and img has 2 styles

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want the header and content section and the image to spread evenly when the viewport is full size but when you shrink the viewport the image should move to the next line.
IF yes, then you can do two things to achieve the desired result:

- introduce flex-wrap: wrap in your container
- remove the width: 100% from wrapper

The css will look like:

```
.section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper {
  /* width: 100%; */
  max-height: 100%
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```